# Finding memory leaks in c++ , jni java code together

Tags: java, c++, memory-leaks, java-native-interface

I need to find memeory leaks in a c++ program which uses JNI calls to call into java apis .

I cant use valgrind as it crashes as soon as java api gets called .

what is alternative to find memory leaks ?

Comment: You must provide more infos.

Comment: This is more of a generic question . What tool to use for finding memory leaks , in case I have a c++ code which calls into java using Jni  calls  . I am on unix . Kindly let  me know what info you are looking for .